# Does Firebase's "Crash Reports" report automatically on a crash?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Let's say I have this:

```
String x = i;
```

and `i` is null, and then, I get a `NullPointerException`. I didn't add any Firebase Logs, so will this be reported? I've setup the SDK and everything, however, when I tried, it didn't report anything, but it says reports may take up to 24 hours. So, will it be reported?

Comment: Yes it will be reported. You can use the logs to add more context around the crash so you can get a better idea of the events that lead up to the crash, but once a fatal exception has occurred it will be reported. You should see logcat messages confirming the generation and sending of the report to Firebase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per Firebase doc to [Create your first error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#create_your_first_error) answer is **Yes**

> Firebase Crash Reporting automatically generates reports for fatal errors (or uncaught exceptions).

But Make sure you follow below steps for [Set up Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#set_up_crash_reporting) for your app:

---

1. If you haven’t already, [set up Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for your Android project.
2. In the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/), add your app to your Firebase project.
3. Add the dependency for Crash Reporting to your app-level `build.gradle` file:

   `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'`
4. Before proceeding, check if your app manifest defines an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object. If that is the case, check the [Known issues](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues) section.

I hope its helps you.

Comment: Thanks, very useful info